# How to edit an element in Angular through routing?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, routes, edit

this is my first question here.
I'm actually studying as full-stack developer but i'm stuck on using ActivatedRoute and the routing stuff.

I have two components (add-category and list-categories) and i want the first one to be able to add and edit elements. Add function is implemented but i have problems with the Edit function.

When i click Edit i'm redirected to add-category/{ID} with the values to be edited and that's fine, but i can't save it.

My intention is to have two components (list-categories and add-category) and use those to respectively show an array of categories and having the possibility to edit or add new elements.

What actually works:
-Add new element.
-Show elements list.
-Delete element.

Now i have the "Edit" button next to every list element, when clicked it redirect me to the "localhost......../{ID}" where i see the actual values of the element. When i try to save the edited elemnt i get errors.

1. POST `http://localhost:5000/api/Category/SaveCategory 999`
2. "ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
   at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:28:1)
   at innerSubscribe (innerSubscribe.js:93:35)
   at push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:41:51)
   at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1754:1)
   at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421:1)
   at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28173:1)
   at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420:1)
   at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188:1)
   at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503:1)
   at invokeTask (zone.js:1671:1)"

I'm trying to use the add-category to add AND edit an element but i'm to do just the first one.

Here is my add-category component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from '../../../services/category.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CategoryDTO } from '../../../models/generics/category.model';
import { DialogService } from '../../../services/dialog.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ListCategoriesComponent } from '../list-categories/list-categories.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-category',
  templateUrl: './add-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-category.component.css']
})
export class AddCategoryComponent implements OnInit {
 
  categoryForm : FormGroup;
  category: CategoryDTO;
  categoryID : number;

  constructor(
    public categoryService : CategoryService, 
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private route : ActivatedRoute,


  ) { 

  }

  goToListCategories() {
    this.router.navigate(['list-categories'])
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.category = new CategoryDTO();
    this.createForm();


    if (this.route.snapshot.params["ID"] != null) {
      const categoryID = this.route.snapshot.params['ID'];
      this.categoryService.getCategoriaByID(categoryID).subscribe(category => {
        this.category = category;
        this.categoryForm.patchValue({
          Nome: category.Nome,
          Descrizione: category.Descrizione,
          EtichettaBreve: category.EtichettaBreve
        });
      });
    }

    /*if (this.route.snapshot.params["ID"] != null) {
      this.categoryService.getCategoriaByID(this.route.snapshot.params["ID"]); 

    */

    
    /*  const categoryId = this.route.snapshot.params['ID'];
      if (categoryId != null) {
        this.categoryService.getCategoriaByID(categoryId).subscribe(category => {
          this.category = category;
          this.categoryForm.patchValue({
            Nome: category.Nome,
            Descrizione: category.Descrizione,
            EtichettaBreve: category.EtichettaBreve
          });
        });
      } else {
        this.category = new CategoryDTO();
      }  
    } 
    }*/
  }
  

  onSaveEdit() {
   
    if (this.categoryForm.valid) {
      this.category.Nome = this.categoryForm.controls['Nome'].value;
      this.category.Descrizione = this.categoryForm.controls['Descrizione'].value;
      this.category.EtichettaBreve = this.categoryForm.controls['EtichettaBreve'].value;
      this.categoryService.saveCategory(this.category).subscribe(() => {
        DialogService.Success("Salvataggio effettuato con successo!");
        this.router.navigate(['/list-categories']);
        this.saveFunction();

      });
    
      } 

    
  }
  
    onSubmit(): void {

      //check form
    
    
      //let CategoryDTO: any;CategoryDTO
      //this.categoryService.saveCategory(this.category).subscribe( res => { console.log('Categoria salvata', res)}),
      //                                                           err => { console.log('Errore', err)};
    
  }

  createForm() {
    
    this.categoryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      Nome: ['', Validators.required],
      Descrizione: ['', Validators.required],
      EtichettaBreve: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

  saveFunction(){
    this.category.Nome = this.categoryForm.controls['Nome'].value
    this.category.Descrizione = this.categoryForm.controls['Descrizione'].value
    this.category.EtichettaBreve = this.categoryForm.controls['EtichettaBreve'].value
    
    this.categoryService                               
    .saveCategory(this.category)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      DialogService.Success("Salvataggio effettuato con successo!");
      this.router.navigate(['/list-categories']);
    })                       
    
  }
}
```

And here is saveCategory in CategoryService:

```
saveCategory(category: CategoryDTO): Observable<CategoryDTO> {
return this.http.post<any>(environment.apiFullUrl + '/Category/SaveCategory', category);
```

}

Comment: show us saveCategory function in categoryService.

Comment: When you try to save the edited element what function do you use?

Comment: onSaveEdit in add-category

Comment: why you call saveFunction() after navigate?

Comment: Because i'm using this component to both add and edit elements

Comment: Suppose we are in editing mode. Why is savefunction called after saveedit is called? Why are you calling the edit api twice?

Comment: Oh right! That's where i'm wrong! I'm calling severous times the same function!